# How to Model the Dispersion Which Is Introduced by an Electro Absorption Modulator (EML)?

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, modulation

I need to model the dispersion which is introduced by an EML in Matlab. The parameters are:

Lambda: 1310nm

PAM4 power:
Pmax = 1.09 mW
Pmin = 0.13 mW

Bandwidth = 56Gbps

Comment: Looks like HW to me. What is the particular problem you are facing?

Comment: Could you please mark my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Dispersion is a frequency dependent phase (Instead of Linear phase).

Just transform your data into Fourier Transform and apply the phase per frequency.

Of course the data must be transformed back into time domain as @Deve noted.

Comment: ...and don't forget to transform it back to time-domain.